# Compactness of $\mathcal K$ in the Hausdorff distance

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Class of Non-empty Compact Subsets of a Compact Metric Space is Compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19091/the-class-of-non-empty-compact-subsets-of-a-compact-metric-space-is-compact)

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space and let $\mathcal K(M)$ denote the set of all non-empty compact subsets of $M$. This collection is a metric space when equipped with the [Hausdorff distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) $h$.

I want to prove$$(M,d)\mbox{ is compact}\implies(\mathcal K,h)\mbox{ is compact}.$$ The statement is true according to the book [V. I. Istratescu, *Fixed Point Theory: An Introduction*], but the proof is omitted. I have already shown that $M$ is complete implies that $\mathcal K$ is complete.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2493757/hausdorff-distance-prove-that-if-e-d-is-complete-then-mathcalke-m

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since $M$ is totally bounded, for each $\epsilon > 0$ there is a finite set $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\} \subseteq M$ such that $\min_{i=1}^n d(x,x_i) < \epsilon$ for all $x \in M$.
For any nonempty compact $C \subseteq M$, if $S = \{x_i: d(C, x_i) < \epsilon\}$ we have
$h(S,C) < \epsilon$.  Thus every $C \in {\cal K}(M)$ is within Hausdorff distance $\epsilon$ of one of the finitely many nonempty subsets of $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$.  This shows that ${\cal K}(M)$ is totally bounded.  Since you already know that ${\cal K}(M)$ is complete,  it is compact.