# Total Boundedness of Finite Sets with 1-Wasserstein Metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, optimal-transport

Let $(X,d)$ be a totally bounded metric space and $\mathcal F(X)$ its set of nonempty finite subsets equipped with the following metric:

$$
d_W(A, B)
= \!\!\! 
\sup_{\substack{f:X\to\mathbb{R}\\\text{1-Lipschitz}}} \left| \frac{1}{|A|}\sum_{a\in A}f(a) - \frac{1}{|B|}\sum_{b\in B}f(b) \right|.
$$

**My question:** Can we show constructively that $(\mathcal F(X),d_W)$ is totally bounded directly from the total boundedness of $X$?

*By "constructively" I mean something like this: For any $\delta>0$ we know that $X=\bigcup_{i=1}^n B^d_\delta(x_i)$ for some $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}\subseteq X$. Can we use these points to construct (for each $\epsilon>0$) a finite collection of sets $\{A_1,\ldots,A_m\}\subseteq \mathcal F(X)$ such that $\mathcal F(X)=\bigcup_{i=1}^m B_\epsilon^{d_W}(A_i)$ by directly using the formula for $d_W$?*

If we replace $d_W$ with the Hausdorff distance $d_H$ then  [the power set works](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/181162/86451). I suspect the power set suffices for $d_W$ as well but have been unable to show it.

---

**Example of "non-constructive" proof:** 
Identifying $A\in\mathcal F(X)$ with the empirical measure $\mu_A=\tfrac{1}{|A|}\sum_{a\in A}\delta_a$ reveals that $d_W$ is just the 1-Wasserstein metric $W$ restricted to the empirical measures via the [Kantorovich-Rubinstein formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric#Dual_representation_of_W1):

$$
W(\mu_A, \nu_A) 
= \!\!\! 
\sup_{\substack{f:X\to\mathbb{R}\\\text{1-Lipschitz}}} \left| \int f\, d\mu_A - \int f\,d\nu_A \right| 
=d_W(A,B).
$$

Since the completion $\overline X$ is compact, general theory tells us the space of probability measures $\mathcal P(\overline X)$ is compact. By slight abuse of notation, we then see that $\mathcal F(X)\subseteq \mathcal P(\overline X)$ is totally bounded because it is a subset of a compact metric space.

Comment: I would use the primal formulation of optimal transport problem and upper bound the distance expression appearing in the of that problem integral by the diameter of the space $X$. Would you consider this a constructive approach though?

Comment: @Giacomo, thank you for your suggestion. However, boundedness of the entire space alone does not entail total boundedness (example: the unit ball in an infinite dimensional Banach space is bounded but not totally bounded). Moreover I am interested in constructing the cover, not just showing one exists.

Comment: Perhaps your suggested approach could work out if there is a way to have boundedness imply total boundedness for this case.